# SQL Assign value to local variable take from table

Tags: sql, select, declare

This i my procedure,that determines classId and liveareaId for Animal to insert it into table

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertAnimal
@name nvarchar,
@birthyear int,
@classname nvarchar,
@livearea nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @classid int
DECLARE @liveareaid int

SET @classid =  

(SELECT Id
 FROM dbo.Class 
 WHERE dbo.Class.Name = @classname)

SET @liveareaid =
(SELECT Id
 FROM dbo.LiveArea 
 WHERE Name = @livearea)

INSERT INTO dbo.Animal (Name,BirthYear,ClassId,LiveAreaId) VALUES
(
    @name,
    @birthyear,
    @classid,
    @liveareaid
)
END
GO
```

I have a error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ClassId', table 'ZOO.dbo.Animal'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Why `ClassId` is null, can you tell me why whis doesn't work.

```
SET @classid =  

(SELECT Id
 FROM dbo.Class 
 WHERE dbo.Class.Name=@classname)
```

Comment: There is data in class table, and classname is supplied is right

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `(n)varchar` variables and parameters that you use. Otherwise, your parameters like `@name`, `@classname` etc. will end up being **exactly 1 character long** - usually *not* what you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have declared `@classname` as only `nvarchar` and have not specified a length. When length is not specified in a `nvarchar` variable declaration statement, the default length is 1.

Declare as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertAnimal
@name nvarchar(10),
@birthyear int,
@classname nvarchar(10),
@livearea nvarchar(10)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insertAnimal
@name nvarchar,
@birthyear int,
@classname nvarchar,
@livearea nvarchar
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @classid int
DECLARE @liveareaid int

SET @classid =  

(SELECT Id
FROM dbo.Class 
WHERE dbo.Class.Name=@classname
AND dbo.Class.Id IS NOT NULL)

SET @liveareaid =
(SELECT Id
FROM dbo.LiveArea 
WHERE Name=@livearea)

INSERT INTO dbo.Animal (Name,BirthYear,ClassId,LiveAreaId) VALUES
(
    @name,
    @birthyear,
    @classid,
    @liveareaid
)
END
GO
```

Comment: Id is a primary key, can't be null

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us which parameteres are passing by you while calling procedure in your page/Query as well as sample data in your database?

It looks like data does not exists in your database according to your parameters in page.

Make sure @classname and @liveareaid data you are passing as a parameter, must be in database table dbo.Class and dbo.LiveArea respectively.

Try below queries first in SQL server.Does it giving any output by same parameters?

```
SELECT Id FROM dbo.Class  WHERE dbo.Class.Name = @classname
SELECT Id FROM dbo.LiveArea  WHERE Name = @livearea
```

Comment: EXEC insertAnimal @name=N'tiger'
   ,@birthyear=1999
   ,@classname=N'class1'
   ,@livearea=N'area1';
THERE IS A class1 in dbo.Class
      AND area1 in dbo.LiveArea

Comment: calling seems Ok. I suppose might be issue with data in tables ! can you  provide structure of table along with sample data ?

Comment: Edited my answer. So,Please check and let me know the outcome